# Find if Google Sheet as IMPORT RANGE through API

Tags: google-sheets, google-client

We're developing a system where we're ingesting Google Sheets into database tables. We wanted to introduce a feature where if the sheet is modified only then it should be considered for ingestion. This would've worked in case of manual changes but not in case of import range.
We're using (google drive)Java library to do this for us. Is there a field which would let us know if there is import range present so that we can skip checking for that file and ingest automatically?